# Unescape JQuery escape(str) in MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, escaping

I am trying to send string from a html text input which may contain single/double quote or &. For example-

```
var name="john's";
```

In ajax part-

```
data: "{'id':'" + id + "','name':'" + escape(name) + "'}",
```

In server side, i'm getting this text as `john%27s`.

How can I get the original text as `john's` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of ASP.NET, you can use the built in function [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("john%27s"); => john's
```

Or in case of JavaScript or jQuery, you can use the function [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI):

```
decodeURI("john%27s"); => john's
```

Correct me if I haven't understood the question clearly! Thanks! :)

Comment: what is the difference between unescape and decodeURI ?

Comment: @SKPaul True, I am not sure. You can use both, whichever works! :)